# Disable message box pop up only when user amending the existing value

Tags: vba, excel

I have vba code which pops up `msg` box if the entered value is zero. if the user later wants to change the zero to some other number it will still pops up the `msg` box before it allows to edit the zero to some other number.

I don’t want the `msgbox` pop up if user is changing the existing value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Intersect(Target, Range("b4:af18")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value = 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            MsgBox "This is it", vbApplicationModal, "Scikess/Holiday"
        End If 

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It shouldn't. `Worksheet_Change` fires _after_ the cell value has been updated. Are you sure you don't code in another event handler, like `Selection_Change` as well? I just tested your code above and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are describing a situation where the user taps the delete key before typing in a new answer. In that case the blank cell has a numerical value of zero and you are getting a false positive on the check to see if the user typed in a zero.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b4:af18")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Dim trgt As Range
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each trgt In Intersect(Target, Range("b4:af18"))
            If trgt.Value = 0 And trgt.Text = "0" Then
                MsgBox "This is it" & Chr(10) & trgt.Address(0, 0) & " cannot be zero.", _
                    vbApplicationModal, "Scikess/Holiday"
                Application.Undo
                trgt.Activate
                Exit For
            End If
        Next trgt

    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I've attempted to have the code run when more than a single Target is involved (e.g. a paste or fill operation) but this makes the `Application.Undo` difficult to keep the other valid entries. Leave a comment on this behavior if it is unsuitable.

It also wasn;t clear on what range you wanted this to react on. You seem to have missed the `Not` in your [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx), making it react on any cell that wasn't in the range. I've adjusted above to include the range you specified, not exclude it.

Comment: Thanks for trying Jeeped..may be I have not put this right. for example when a user has enters zero in tab called absence sheet then it needs to display msgbox asking user to enter the absence hours in next tab which is called leave hours tab.. However some times the user might put zero accidentally and want to change that.. so here msg box pops up after changing the value to say like 5 and when hit enter by the user. I'm looking for solution where I the msg box will not pop up if they are removing the zero which was entered already. Hope this makes sense and thanks again.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Rang                                       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b4:af18")) Is Nothing Then                                         If Target.Value = 0 Then                                                                        MsgBox "Pls enter the holiday hours in next tab", vbApplicationModal, "Sickness/Holiday"

End If  end if end sub